# Will onRestoreInstanceState() still be called when activity is recreated?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Quick question: In some cases, an activity will need to be destroyed to free up resources. In that scenario, when the user navigates back to said activity, onCreate() will first be called. I'm asking if onRestoreInstanceState() will still be called if ever that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will.

First `onCreate()` is called with the saved instance state as a bundle. Then `onStart()` is called. Then `onRestoreInstanceState()` is called with the same bundle that was passed to `onCreate()`.

This gives you the option to restore the state **either** in `onCreate()` or in `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Answer (score 0):

`onRestoreInstanceState()` method is called after `onStart()` when the activity is being re-initialized from a previously saved state, given here in `savedInstanceState`

Comment: Uhmm, that doesn't really answer my question.